# Prove that $\frac{b-a}{b}< \ln(\frac{b}{a})<\frac{b-a}{a}$

Tags: inequality

So I have hardships trying to prove that $\frac{b-a}{b}< \ln(\frac{b}{a})<\frac{b-a}{a}$, where $\, 0<a<b$.

Now I have that $\mathrm{e}^{b-a}> \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^b $ and $\mathrm{e}^{b-a}> \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^a $.

It might be wrong, but seems right to me. Anyways, I don't feel like I'm closer to the solution knowing these. Could you help me out, please?

Comment: $$\ln \frac{b}{a} = \int_a^b \frac{1}{t}\,dt$$

Comment: take the base to either sides separate inequality as $e^\frac {b-a}{b}is less than b/a$ and same for other with a greater than sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all real $x\ne0$, we have $e^x > 1+x$, which implies $x > \ln(1+x)\text{ for }x>-1$.

Now set $1+x=\frac{b}{a}$ (so $x>0$)

$$\begin{align}
1+x=\frac{b}{a} \iff x=\frac{b-a}{a} \\[2ex] 
\implies \frac{b-a}{a}>\ln\left(\frac{b}{a}\right) \tag{1}
\end{align}$$

Now set $1+x=\frac{a}{b}$ (so $x>-1,x\ne0$)

$$\begin{align}
1+x=\frac{a}{b} \iff x=\frac{a-b}{b} \\[2ex] 
\implies \frac{a-b}{b}>\ln\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) \\[2ex]
\implies \frac{b-a}{b}<-\ln\left(\frac{a}{b}\right) \\[2ex]
\implies \frac{b-a}{b}<\ln\left(\frac{b}{a}\right) \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

Together (1) and (2) prove the required inequality.

Comment: Wow, very nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

Let's prove that, for $t>0$, $t\ne 1$,
$$
\ln t<t-1
$$
Indeed
$$
f(t)=1-t+\ln t
$$
has derivative $f'(t)=(1-t)/t$, so the function has a maximum at $t=1$ and $f(1)=0$. Therefore $f(t)<0$, for all $t>0$, $t\ne 1$.

In particular, we also have
$$
\ln(1/t)<1/t-1
$$
so
$$
1-\frac{1}{t}<\ln t
$$
(except at $t=1$).

Now just use $t=b/a$.

If you want to use the integral mean value, since the maximum of $t\mapsto 1/t$ in $[a,b]$ is at $a$ and the minimum is at $b$, we have
$$
(b-a)\frac{1}{b}<\int_{a}^b\frac{1}{t}\,dt<(b-a)\frac{1}{a}
$$

Answer (score 0):

We are given $0<a<b$. Hence, $\frac{a}{b-a} < \frac{b}{b-a}$.

Now suppose, $f(x) = \ln{x}$. Suppose also that $c$ lies between $\frac{a}{b-a}$ and $\frac{b}{b-a}$. Hence, if we now apply the Mean Value Theorem here, we will get $$f^\prime(c) = \frac{f(\frac{b}{b-a})-f(\frac{a}{b-a})}{\frac{b}{b-a}-\frac{a}{b-a}}$$ $$= \frac{\ln{(\frac{b}{b-a})-\ln(\frac{a}{b-a})}}{\frac{b}{b-a}-\frac{a}{b-a}}$$ Or $$f^\prime(c)=\ln{\frac{b}{a}}$$ Since $f(x) = \ln{x}\tag{1}\label{eq1}$ we have $f^\prime(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. Therefore, $$f^\prime(c)=\frac{1}{c}\tag{2}\label{eq2}$$ From (1) and (2), we get $$c=\frac{1}{\ln{\frac{b}{a}}}\tag{3}\label{eq3}$$ Since, $c$ lies between $\frac{a}{b-a}$ and $\frac{b}{b-a}$, we have $$\frac{a}{b-a} < c < \frac{b}{b-a}$$ Or $$\frac{b-a}{b}<\frac{1}{c}<\frac{b-a}{a}$$ Or, from equation (3) $$\frac{b-a}{b}<\ln{\frac{b}{a}}<\frac{b-a}{a}$$